# How to ground a 3prong outlet for a cloth dryer?

Tags: wiring

Can I run a grounding from an outlet next to a 3 prong outlet to convert it to a 4 prong outlet for un electric cloth dryer?

Comment: Replace the cord. If you have an existing 3 prong outlet, you are not required to replace it with a 4 prong.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrofit just the ground. However you need to run the ground in #10 wire either back to the panel, back to somewhere that has a #10 ground coming out of that panel (e.g. a water heater), or to metallic conduit coming out of that panel.  A #12 ground path is not  adequate.

You may also not use water pipes, since they *might* be part of the grounding electrode system, but they are not part of the equipment safety grounding system.

There is a legal exception that allows  you to not ground a dryer.  However the exception tells you to bootleg ground off of neutral - exactly what they tell you *not* to do anywhere else, and for good reason.  Any flaw in the neutral wire will result in the dryer's chassis becoming electrified at 120V.